# Finding the total number of databases across all servers/instances

Tags: t-sql

My manager wants to be able to run a script/job to find the total number of databases currently on all instances/servers.

I know to use: select  COUNT(*) from sys.databases
But what's the easiest way to get this to run against all instances so that when he runs it, it counts all for him as opposed to running it against each instance separately?

Answer (score 0):

To query data from different databases/servers, you need Linked Servers. You can get to them in SQL Server Management Studio under

```
Server Objects-->Linked Servers
```

Once you have that, you can call data from other servers like so:

```
select
    *
from
    sys.databases,
    [OtherServerName].[OtherDB].[sys].[databases]
```

Then build a query to cover all your instances.